# Does EL&U support an em-dash or en-dash

Tags: support

I'm able to paste an em-dash character. But I was wondering if there's a way to place an em-dash or an en-dash into an answer? The tag &endash; doesn't work. I could not find them among the whitelisted HTML tags at [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: It's spelt &ndash; (and &mdash;) and yes it does work

Comment: Perfect, thank you. @MattE.Эллен, is there a SO or EL&U page that has other symbols?

Comment: There's no page as far as I'm aware. But, in questions and answers (not comments or chat) you can use any HTML entity reference.

Comment: Any workarounds for using them in comments ?

Comment: I find it faster to type codes. On Windows, it's Alt-0150 and Alt-0151 for the en dash and em dash respectively; Alt-0145 through Alt-0148 for the open and close single and double quotes; and so on.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Exchange supports the html character sequences for various dashs and hyphens:

- &shy; — Wo­rd with soft hyphen in it
- &mdash; — Wo—rd with an em-dash in it
- &hyphen; — Wo‐rd with a hyphen in it
- &ndash; — Wo–rd with an en-dash in it

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the nudge in the right direction, Matt. Here's a site that has em-dash (use `&mdash;`) and en-dash (use `&ndash;`).

http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html

Also helpful for “André owes me €50.”

```
Desired                 HTML sequence       numeric keyboard shortcut
em-dash (—)             &mdash;                Alt-0151
en-dash (–)             &ndash;                Alt-0150
```